# how to put progress dialog inside a linear layout: Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, progressdialog

I have a Relative layout for my fragment. 
Inside this layout I have a bunch of child views, one of which is a Linear Layout, which shows some pictorial data. 
This data comes from the cloud and thus takes some time.
While this data is on the way, I would like to show a progress dialog kind of a thing, but but only in place of the Linear Layout, I would like the rest of the fragment to be still visible and user should be able to use the rest of the views.

Could someone please suggest some ideas?

Thanks

UDPATE: Adding XML layout file containing the Relative Layout rl_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_txt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/age_txt"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/age_txt"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="AM/PM"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photo_pic_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="180dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plug_chart_title_txt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >
    </LinearLayout>


     <Switch
         android:id="@+id/switch"
         android:layout_width="160dip"
         android:layout_height="35dip"
         android:track="@drawable/btntoggle_selector" 
         android:layout_below="@id/photo_pic_layout"
         android:thumb="@drawable/button"
         android:textOn=""
         android:thumbTextPadding="40dip"
         android:textOff=""
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to show the progress dialog in place of LinearLayout: @id/photo_pic_layout

Answer (score 0):

you can use use ProgressBar for showing the background work...

you can not add progress dialog in layout. A progress dialog is window context which comes over the Activity window.when progress dialog is shown, you can not touch the Views in Activity. and if you touch outside the progress dialog, dialog will be closed if you set `progressDialog.setCancelable(true)` and `progressDialog.setCancelOnTouchOutsie(true)`.

Comment: but the problem is that the user would not be use the fragment till the progress dialog goes away

Comment: progressDialog.setCancelable(false) and progressDialog.setCancelOnTouchOutsie(false). user can not use Fragment until work is done. don't forget to call progressDialog.dismiss() when work is done...

Answer (score 0):

for a complete example of doing a async task with a progress bar:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

you can load the image asynchronously , and show a progress bar in the linear layout.

you would require a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

something like this, source: ([process bitmaps async](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html))

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100));
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for adding a progressbar in your layout file:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     ... >
     <ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/loading" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: regarding your comments

have you tried this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photo_pic_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="180dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plug_chart_title_txt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

             <ProgressBar
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

does it show the progress bar?

Comment: but is it possible to add a progress bar to a linear layout

Comment: yes it is possible, a progress bar is just another view and can be added to a viewGroup (like linear layout) (P.S : see the edit for a tutorial)

Comment: are you able to follow or do i need to edit the answer to step by step

Comment: nope, i think i follow. But my only concern is that this linear layout is inside a Relative Layout which is the view of the fragment. So, cld u pls show code for putting it into the LL.

Comment: can you edit your question and post your layout file for the fragment

Comment: added the whole xml layout file

Comment: before acyually implementing the async task, try to see if the above code shows the progress bar, it should be visible by default